# Custom List Header Column Sort/Filter

Tags: custom-list, css, filter, formatting

I'm trying to re-format the sort/filter drop down box on the column header of a custom list (font-family, font-size, background etc).

This appears to be possible by using the following rule in a script editor, but the rule currently affects other elements on the SharePoint page. If someone could let me know how to make it specific to the custom list it would be much appreciated:

```
<style>

body,.ms-core-defaultFont,#pageStatusBar,.ms-status-msg,.js-callout-body 
{

 font-family: "Arial","Segoe UI","Segoe",Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
}

</style>
```

Thanks in advance.

29/7 - Still struggling to find a resolution to allow me to format the sort/filter drop down box. Has anyone else managed to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try below steps:

1. Add a content editor web part on View Page.
2. Insert below content into it.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .ms-viewheadertr { 
          //your style 
        }
    </style>
```

**.ms-viewheadertr** class works to customize column header.

Comment: Thanks Divya. I appreciate the reply. I've managed to customise the column header though. It's specifically the drop down box that appears when the sort/filter arrow on a column header is clicked that I'm looking to format. Any idea of the class to help with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below class to format the dropdown.

`.ms-core-menu-list` for the div of dropdown

`.ms-core-menu-link` - for the links inside the dropdown

Here is the demo.

[image]